# Executing an asynchronous code when "exit" event is emitted

Tags: javascript, events, node.js

I want to execute an asynchronous callback when `exit` event is emitted. For example:

```
process.addListener ("exit", function (){
    asynchronousCode (function (){
        //my callback
    });
});
```

I've tried both with `addListener` and `on` but the code inside the callback is never executed because the program emits the `exit` event, executes the asynchronous function and terminates without calling the callback.

How can I force the program to wait until I execute `process.emit ("exit")`? Or maybe the code must be synchronous...

Comment: I'm not sure why code for page unload should be asynchronous, you should prevent the default behavior of the event (set e.preventDefault to true or return false) and keep a state variable used in asynchronousCode() (set it to true then move the current location). Anyway the user will "exit" the page and after a little bit (while he can still interact) everything will disappear...I guess it's a little bit confusing for him.

Comment: I'm not writting an http server, I just want to do some actions when the program finishes. The `exit` event does not pass any parameter to the listener.

Comment: I talked about the unload event anyway I guess it doesn't make so much sense to do something asynchronous on the exit (because the only way to complete it is to postpone the exit itself then you'll make it...syncrhonous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cf78ce59b3c0a9e7cdcdbd84d71300b04150b6df/doc/api/process.markdown):

Emitted when the process is about to exit. This is a good hook to perform constant time checks of the module's state (like for unit tests). The main event loop will no longer be run after the 'exit' callback finishes, so timers may not be scheduled.

```
process.on('exit', function () {
  process.nextTick(function () {
   console.log('This will not run');
  });
  console.log('About to exit.');
});
```

So you cannot use an asynchronous function in this handler.

Comment: Well, I've also read this code snippet but I thought that there was some workaround.

Comment: what kind of function are you trying to call?

Comment: I want to remove a directory an all its content, so: stat, unlink, readdir, rmdir

Comment: that's fine then, the fs module provide an xxSync method for most xx methods (http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) so I think you should be able to do what you want.